# In GUID Partition Table how can I know how many partitions there are?

Tags: guid, disk-partitioning, guid-partition-table

I have a image of a USB with 3 partitions:

- Partition 1: FAT32
- Partition 2: exFAT
- Partition 3: NTFS

I am making a program that goes trough the partitions, but I am unsure of how I can know how many partitions my program should look for. By looking at the raw data I can see that it has three partitions as expected, but off course my program doesnt know this.

I tried to look at "80 (0x50)   4 bytes     Number of partition entries in array" but in my example it gave me value 128 (0x80000000).

Here are screenshots of hex from my example image.

**Protective MBR**
[image]

**Partition table header (LBA 1)**
[image]

```
signature=- HexLe=4546492050415254 HexBe=5452415020494645
revisionHexLe=000001 HexLe=4546492050415254 HexBe=5452415020494645
headerSizeDec=92 HexLe=5C000000 HexBe=0000005C
crc2OfHeaderDec=82845332 HexLe=941EF004 HexBe=04F01E94
reservedADec=0 HexLe=00000000 HexBe=00000000
currentLBADec=1 HexLe=0100000000000000 HexBe=0000000000000001
backupLBADec=30277631 HexLe=FFFFCD0100000000 HexBe=0000000001CDFFFF
firstUsableLBAForPartitionsDec=34 HexLe=2200000000000000 HexBe=0000000000000022
lastUsableLBADec=30277598 HexLe=DEFFCD0100000000 HexBe=0000000001CDFFDE
diskGUIDHexMe=8B3F71C5AF9D744D9CA3EBFF7D1F9DC9
startingLBAOfArrayOfPartitionEntriesDec=2 HexLe=0200000000000000 HexBe=0000000000000002
numberOfPartitionEntriesInArrayDec=128 HexLe=80000000 HexBe=00000080
sizeOfASinglePartitionEntryDec=128 HexLe=80000000 HexBe=00000080
crc2OfPartitionEntriesArrayDec=-2043475264 HexLe=C00A3386 HexBe=86330AC0
reservedBDec=00000000 HexLe=00000000 HexBe=00000000
We are going to look for partitions now at offset 1024
```

**Partition entries (LBA 2–33)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, and you may have already figured it out by now.

Refer following figure from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) page. Wiki page itself will provide you further information.

It is not possible to determine the number of partitions just by looking at the GUID partition table [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_table_header_(LBA_1)) at LBA1, you have to examine the partition [entries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries_(LBA_2%E2%80%9333)) and check whether the [Partition type GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) says it is unused (all zeros) or not.

Number of partition entries in the header at offset 80 (=0x50) is the total number of entries as determined by the size of a single partition entry at offset 84.

[image: gpt]